# DocuSign - Sharepoint List integration

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate, sharepoint-list

Hello I'm currently stuck creating a powerautomate flow between DocuSign and MS lists. I'm  working on a project and I need for our employees to complete that Docusign form and for the information on that to be updated on a MS list. Can anyone with experience help me with that workflow?  Thanks.

I've attempted several flows but I'm not understanding how to get the information to the list from the Docusign envelope.

Answer (score -1):

checkout this blog which contains the common tasks after a docusign envelope (form) is completed. https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/expanding-power-automate-series-common-post-signing-tasks

Comment: Link-only answers are not valid answers.